# using awk to replace a string by another string (mapping table contained in a file)

Tags: awk

I would like to know if it's possible to do the following thing only using
awk:
I am searching some regex in a file Fand I want to replace the string (S1) that matches
the regex by another string (S2). Of course, it's easy to do that with awk. But ... my
problem is that the value of S2 has to be obtained from another file that maps
S1 to S2.

Example :

### file F:

```
abcd 168.0.0.1 qsqsjsdfjsjdf
sdfsdffsd
168.0.0.2 sqqsfjqsfsdf
```

### my associative table in another file

```
168.0.0.1 foo
168.0.0.2 bar
```

I want to get:

### this result:

```
abcd foo qsqsjsdfjsjdf
sdfsdffsd
bar sqqsfjqsfsdf
```

Thanks for help !

**edit**: if my input file is a bit different, like this (no space before IP address):

### file F:

```
abcd168.0.0.1 qsqsjsdfjsjdf
sdfsdffsd
168.0.0.2 sqqsfjqsfsdf
```

i can't use $1, $2 variables and search in the associative array.
I tried something like that (based on birei proposition) but it did not work :

```
FNR < NR {
    sub(/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/, assoc [ & ] );
    print
}
```

Is there a way to search the matched string in the associative array (assoc[ & ] seems to
be not valid) ?

Comment: If it is a one-off problem, put the table in the `BEGIN` section and query it then with your awk script. E.g., `BEGIN { t[x1] = y; t[x2] = y; ... } { if ($1 in t) ...; }`

Answer (score 5):

One way. It's self-explanatory. Save data from the associative table in an array and in second file check for each field if it matches any key of the array:

```
awk '
    FNR == NR {
        assoc[ $1 ] = $2;
        next;
    }
    FNR < NR {
        for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) {
            if ( $i in assoc ) {
                $i = assoc[ $i ]
            }
        }
        print
    }
' associative_file F
```

Output:

```
bcd foo qsqsjsdfjsjdf                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
sdfsdffsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
bar sqqsfjqsfsdf
```

---

**EDIT**: Try following `awk` script for IPs without spaces with their surrounding words. It's similar to previous one, but now it searches in the array and try to find an IP in any place of the line (default `$0` for `gsub`) and substitutes it.

```
awk '
    FNR == NR {
        assoc[ $1 ] = $2;
        next;
    }
    FNR < NR {
        for ( key in assoc ) {
            gsub( key, assoc[ key ] )
        }
        print
    }
' associative_file F
```

Assuming `infile` with the conten of your second example of file `F`, output would be:

```
abcdfoo qsqsjsdfjsjdf                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
sdfsdffsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
bar sqqsfjqsfsdf
```

Comment: You should do `if (i in assoc)` instead of `if (assoc[$i])` because the latter creates an entry in the array simply by referring to it.  You can omit the `FNR < NR` selector since it will always be true (because of the `next`). You can omit the `$0 = $0` since the `$i =` assignments do any field recomputing necessary.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Thank you. Good suggestions. I like the explicit comparison of `FNR < NR`, so I left it in the code. Others I agree that can be considered flaws, so I modified them.

Comment: thanks a lot ! it solved my problem and I learn that I have many things to learn about awk. so powerful tool ...

Comment: I added a small modification to the input file and I am now looking for a small modification to Birei proposition

Comment: @jean: I edited the answer but I suggest you to remove this answer as the accepted one at this time because the question is not solved yet and could avoid that some users also try to provide other solutions.